# Building recipients while sending an email gives me an exception with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send an email and if it has cc, it will be sent with cc.

```
public $content;
public $subject;
public $filename;
public $user_id;
public $cc;

public function __construct($content,$subject,$filename,$user_id,$cc = null)
{

    $this->content = $content;
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->filename = $filename;
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->cc = $cc;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    if($this->cc){
    return $this->from("my@email.io")
        ->subject($this->subject)
        ->cc($this->cc)
        ->attach(storage_path() . "/app/public/files/" . $this->user_id . "/" . $this->filename)
        ->view('emails.sent');
    }else{
        return $this->from("my@email.io")
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->attach(storage_path() . "/app/public/files/" . $this->user_id. "/" .$this->filename)
            ->view('emails.sent');
    }
}
```

This controller worked flawlessly before I introduced the cc logic, but after I added the if else to the build function, Laravel sends me this error:

> ErrorException in Mailable.php line 241: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()

Which is this function:

```
protected function buildRecipients($message)
    {
        foreach (['to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo'] as $type) {
            foreach ($this->{$type} as $recipient) {
                $message->{$type}($recipient['address'], $recipient['name']);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I have tried both with and without adding $cc when calling a function, and it always gives me the same error. As I said this worked before I introduced the if else.

I already solved this by creating 2 different Mail controllers, but I would like to know why this solution doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your PHP version? Because the short array syntax you are using only works from 5.4 up

Comment: put a check(isset($this->{$type}) etc, whatever is suitable) before second foreach loop in function buildRecipients. As i dont see any 'to' or 'replyTo' properties in your pasted code.

Comment: @Amarnasan 7.0.4

Comment: @JoshulSharma The "to" is sent from another controller, but I will check it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually renamed the variable $cc to $mycc and it works again.

Since the class extended `Mailable`, and Mailable already has a variable called `$cc`, which is supposed to be an array, my `$cc = null` overwrote the variable.

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to get this solved.  I kept thinking there couldn't be a problem with the Mailable class, but it sure seemed like it.  Overriding the $cc var was the problem.  Crazy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ErrorException in Mailable.php line 241: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

it means that argument passed to the foreach is not an array. According to your code it means that one of the 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo' properties is either empty or not an array. I'd suggest to add is_array check before foreach.

Thanks.